# Rails 4 Query .where with an array variable

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-4, relationships

I am trying to figure out how to write a query that I can use a .where and a variable that holds an array of day preferences that will query my events table for those preferences.

```
Event Model
    belongs_to :event_type
    has_many :sub_events, dependent: :destroy

User Model
  has_many :user_sub_events
  has_many :sub_events, through: :user_sub_events
  has_many :user_preferences
  has_many :preferences, through: :user_preferences

Preference Model
    has_many :user_preferences
    has_many :users, through: :user_preferences
    belongs_to :preference_type

class UserPreference < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user 
    belongs_to :preference
end
```

And this is where I am trying to run the query.  In the userscontroller.  I have a dashboard method set up.

```
def dashboard
    @preferences = current_user.preferences.where(preference_type_id: 1)
    @suggested_tasks = Event.where(day: ['Monday', 'Friday'])
end
```

So I get that I can query on my user's preferences, and the preference_type_id: 1 is the daily preferences.  So I grab that in the @preferences variable.  Then in the @suggested_tasks variable, is where I want to query on what is inside the @preferences variable.  So I need to replace the ['Monday', 'Friday'] array with whatever is inside the @preferences variable.

If I output what is in the @preferences variable in my view, I get:

Thanks for the response.  Yes, I will get the user preferences in the @preferences variable.  So if I output @preferences in my view, i get

```
Monday
Friday
Tuesday
Wednesday
```

Which are what user preferences I selected and are stored in the through table User_Preferences.

I'm trying to use an 'in' clause in the query, but now im getting an error:

`Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT`events`.* FROM`events`WHERE (day in (SELECT`preferences`.* FROM`preferences`INNER JOIN`user_preferences`ON`preferences`.`id`=`user_preferences`.`preference_id`WHERE`user_preferences`.`user_id`= 1 AND`preferences`.`preference_type_id`= 1))`

My query is:

```
preferences = current_user.preferences.where(preference_type_id: 1)
@suggested_tasks = Event.where("day in (?)", preferences)
```

Comment: At the moment do you get multiple records in `@preferences`? can you output some of the data...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured this out.  I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but this is my new queries.  This grabs the current user's preferences from the through table.  Then it queries the Event table for those mapped to the preference name (which is the string value of the day).  So, basically in the user preference table, it stores a string of the day.  And in the Event table, it stores the string value of the day which is parsed from the date that is created for that object using strftime(%A).

```
@preferences = current_user.preferences.where(preference_type_id: 1)
@suggested_tasks = Event.where('day in (?)', @preferences.map {|x| x.name })
```

Comment: have you tried to do a .select(:name) in your query for @preferences? then you should be able to get rid of the map and everything stays in activerecord/the database.